# help with my logic for building a query from inputs

Tags: php

I have 4 input fields and its driving me crazy because i can't figure out when to dynamically add the AND condition

right now my raw query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `staff`
" . $where . $location . "
" . $and_1 . $expertise . "
" . $and_2 . $education . "
" . $and_3 . $salary . "
ORDER BY 
`created_on` DESC LIMIT " . $limit;
```

because I want to allow for blank fields to add less conditions to the query I have been trying to figure out the logic that would add `WHERE` and `AND` to each condition depending on the amount of conditions being requested.

My attemps:

```
($location == '' ? $location = '' : $location = '`location` = "'.$location.'"');
($expertise == '' ? $expertise = '' : $expertise = '`expertise` = "' . $expertise . '"');
($education == '' ? $education = '' : $education = '`education` = "' . $education . '"');
($location != '' && ($expertise != '' || $education != '') ? $and_1 = 'AND ' : $and_1 = '');
($location != '' && ($and_1 != '') ? $and_2 = 'AND ' : $and_2 = '');
($and_1 != '' || $and_2 != '' && $salary != 'no preference' ? $salary : '');
($and_1 == '' || $and_2 == '' && $salary != 'no preference' ? '' : $salary);
```

I think I'm just getting lost in my own mental logic as I'm coding that I'm not even understanding my own code logic lol ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to have your HTML inputs, but here's a solution that doesn't even need to mess with taking some parts of the query out or not.

```
//do for each input
//or similar check to create empty string when there's not a valid input.
$input = is_empty($input) ? '' : $input;
```

...

```
SELECT *
FROM staff
WHERE location LIKE '%$location%'
AND expertise LIKE '%$expertise%'
AND education LIKE '%$education%'
AND salary LIKE '%$salary%'
```

For a range of salaries, you will need to do a check, similar to what you were thinking in your question.

First, set `$salary` to what you need it to be, either `$salary = 'no preference';` or `$salary = array($num1, $num2);`.  This should be done when you are checking the other inputs.

Build your base query with the stuff that can use `LIKE`:

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM staff
          WHERE location LIKE '%$location%'
          AND expertise LIKE '%$expertise%'
          AND education LIKE '%$education%'";
```

Once you've done that, build the salary clause based on the content of $salary:

```
if( is_array($salary) )
{
  $query .= " AND salary BETWEEN $salary[0] AND $salary[1]";
}
else
{
  $query .= " AND salary LIKE '%no preference%'";
  //or "AND salary = 'no preference'" if that field is exactly that
};
```

Then you can execute `$query`.  Note, you need to sanitize your inputs in case the user tries to do something malicious in your queries.

Comment: oooh, duh! i didn't even think of doing it that way, I was stuck up and having the query being build programatically. For salary I have a BETWEEN caluse. how would i use the Like clause with that? the results for $salary is either 'no preference' or 20000 - 30000 which is access with $salary[0] and $salary[1] after exploding it

Comment: I've updated my answer.  It wouldn't fit here.  Also, I suggest you look into the answer @experimentX gave.  I think it would ultimately be more flexible and clean in your situation.  My answer should work and will probably be easier to understand, but I think his answer is better and more powerful.

Answer (score 2):

```
$location = ($location)?'`location` = "'.$location.'"':null;
....
....
```

More exactly

```
$vars = array(
    ($location)?'`location` = "'.$location.'"'): null,
    /**
    ...
    ...
    **/
 );

function myfilterarray($var)
{
    return !empty($var)?$var: null;
}

$newvars = array_filter($vars, 'myfilterarray');

$where = join(" AND ", $newvars);
```